# Do taxonomies exist only at the site collection level? Or at the sub-site level as well?

Tags: site-collection, site, taxonomy

I have a question about taxonomies.

Do they exist at only the site collection level? Or can you specify unique taxonomies at the sub-site level as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two types of Term Groups:

- **Global Term Group**. Managed via the central administration UI. Read-only access from all site collections and sites.
- **Site Collection Term Group**. Managed on the site collection level. Read-only access can be granted to other site collections using "[Site Collection Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-a-term-set-available-to-other-site-collections-in-sharepoint-5e1271e2-6e1f-4d22-8a0d-b2648a412ca7)" (in SharePoint Online Only).

[image: Term Groups types]

**Subsite Term Group** does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

They exist in the central term store (MMS SA) and Site Collection (terms themselves are in the MMS SA, but the SA has a pointer to the specific Site Collection).

Subwebs do not have their own taxonomy stores.